# External regret algorithms playing dominated strategies

Tags: game-theory, online-algorithms

Edit 3/14 to refer to textbook question:

I am trying to understand the concept of external regret better, and am working through the Nisan et al. (eds.) Algorithmic Game Theory book ([https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sandholm/cs15-892F13/algorithmic-game-theory.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esandholm/cs15-892F13/algorithmic-game-theory.pdf)). I am looking for insights on the second part of Problem 4.8 on p. 101: "Show that there are cases in which the external regret of a player can be small, yet it gives $\varepsilon$-dominated actions high weight." Can you give me a pointer?